# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers issue on working codes

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

At first the errors following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http
>   headers in /var/www/me/public_html/soap.php:62 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://dgpysws....', 'urn:login', 2, 0) #1
>   /var/www/me/public_html/soap.php(62): SoapClient->__call('login',
>   Array) #2 /var/www/me/public_html/soap.php(62):
>   SoapClient->login(Object(stdClass)) #3 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/me/public_html/soap.php on line 62

My codes were working perfect but a few days ago getting that errors.

I tried all things on Google and SO thats:

1. INI SET: `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 100);`
2. SOAP initialize options: `'connection_timeout' => '100'`
3. SOAP initialize options: `'keep_alive' => false`
4. PHP Version `5.4` to `5.6` upgrade.

My tried codes:

```
$options = array(
        'trace'       => true,
        'exceptions'  => true,
        'keep_alive'  => false,
        'connection_timeout'  => 100,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    );
$client = new SoapClient("http://dgpysws.epias.com.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis.wsdl", $options);

$p1 = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->UserName = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->UserName->v = "USERNAME";
$p1->loginMessage->Password = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->Password->v = "PASSWORD";

$client->login($p1);
```

I can get all types with:

```
$client->__getTypes(); // works
```

But i cant login:

```
 $client->login($p1); // not works
```

*Note: WSDL url is IP protected. You cant get it.*

Comment: This issue solved spontaneously :S Thx, all!

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing this on multiple (CentOS, Linux, Windows 7, Windows 8) platforms through the unsupported but Salesforce-supplied SOAP interface library,
from both Utah and Oregon.

We therefore strongly suspect it is a Salesforce problem.

My previous workarounds have used similar techniques as that above, increasing
both timeouts to 600 and NOT messing with keep_alive or soap_version .